# Tapestry 5 - decouple page class name from URL

Tags: java, webserver, tapestry

Is there any baked-in way, or established Tapestry pattern, to decouple the name of a page Class from the URL which renders it?

My specific problem is that I have a page class in an English codebase but I want the URLs to be in another language.

For example, the `Hello.java` page should be accessible from **www.example.com/hola** rather than the standard **www.example.com/hello** - though it's fine if both of these URLs work.

Ideally I want something like an annotation to configure a different URL name in-place for each individual page class.

Off the top of my head I could solve this myself with a map of URLs to page class names and a custom `RequestFilter` to do the mapping on each request - but I don't want to reinvent the wheel if there's a baked-in way to do this or a better pattern that anyone can suggest?

Comment: Note, a RequestFilter would only solve half the problem (inbound requests). You still have to solve the other problem of url generation (eventlink / pagelink etc).

Comment: That's what I'm wondering - if I was to generate urls in the foreign language for eventlinks and pagelinks would they go back through the inbound translation? I'm sort of doing the opposite of what's discussed in Igor's blog post - I'm not changing the page name and trying to still make it work with the old url purely for backwards compatibility, I'm trying to keep the same page name but enable (and for internal links, force) the use of a new url.

Comment: I think you'll need to decorate the ```ComponentEventLinkEncoder``` for URL generation (outgoing). You can choose to handle inbound URLs either with a ```RequestFilter``` or again in ```ComponentEventLinkEncoder```.

Answer (score 1):

Tapestry has a [LinkTransformer](http://tapestry.apache.org/5.3/apidocs/org/apache/tapestry5/services/linktransform/LinkTransformer.html) but I've always found the API lacking since you don't have access to the default behaviour. Igor has written a blog post about the LinkTransformer API [here](http://blog.tapestry5.de/index.php/2010/09/06/new-url-rewriting-api/)

I've always found it necessary to decorate the ComponentEventLinkEncoder so that I can access the default behaviour and tweak it. See [ModeComponentEventLinkEncoder.java](https://github.com/uklance/tapestry-sandbox/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/uklance/mode/ModeComponentEventLinkEncoder.java) and [AppModule.java](https://github.com/uklance/tapestry-sandbox/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/uklance/services/AppModule.java#L40) for an example which tweaks the default behaviour and does some string manipulation on the URL.

Thiago has created a url rewriter api [here](https://github.com/thiagohp/tapestry-url-rewriter) but I've never used it myself. I'm pretty sure his solution is based on decorating the ComponentEventLinkEncoder for outbound URLs and a RequestFilter for inbound URLs.

Answer (score 1):

Tynamo's [tapestry-routing](http://tynamo.org/tapestry-routing+guide) could help you. It depends on how do you want to generate the links to www.example.com/hola and www.example.com/hello

The @At annotation only allows one route per page, but you can contribute all the routes you want via your AppModule, like this:

```
@Primary
@Contribute(RouteProvider.class)
public static void addRoutes(OrderedConfiguration<Route> configuration, ComponentClassResolver componentClassResolver) {
    String pageName = componentClassResolver.resolvePageClassNameToPageName(Home.class.getName());
    String canonicalized = componentClassResolver.canonicalizePageName(pageName);
    configuration.add("home1", new Route("/home1", canonicalized));
    configuration.add("home2", new Route("/home2", canonicalized));
    configuration.add("home3", new Route("/home3", canonicalized));
    configuration.add("home4", new Route("/home4", canonicalized));
    configuration.add("hola", new Route("/hola", canonicalized)); // the last one is going to be use by default to create links to the page
}
```

The routes are ordered and by default the last one is going to be used to generate the links. 
Currently there is no way to avoid using the default route to generate the links.

Comment: This is rewriting my internal page links to the new urls but it doesn't seem to route the urls back to the page - is this how it's supposed to work - just one way for link rewriting? Looking at the source this seems purposeful - it explicitly does nothing to intervene in the request in RouterLinkTransformer.decodePageRenderRequest()

Comment: No this is not how it's supposed to work, the route is bidirectional. The RouterLinkTransformer is not part of the request-processing pipeline, RouterDispatcher.dispatch is in charge of routing the request to the right page. If the contributions are not working try first with a single @At annotation and no contributions to get a feeling of how this should work.

Comment: Ah yeah, that makes sense - I was confusing it with the ComponentEventLinkEncoder interface. Anyway the RouterDispatcher is never called for me because a custom ComponentClassResolver in my project always defaults the rendered page to the home page on tapestry's PageRenderDispatcher, meaning it always returns true and never defers to RouterDispatcher which is configured to run afterwards. Anyway I guess tapestry-routing is in general a good solution but it will take some effort to integrate it with my app. Thanks for pointing me at it!